# CuPy sparse kernels

Tags: sparse-matrix, cupy

What is the API for writing a custom (Elementwise or Raw) kernel that works on cuSPARSE instances in CuPy? If I want to write a kernel that can take `cupyx.scipy.sparse.csr_matrix` instances as argument, what arguments does the underlying CUDA code need to take?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it (at least approximately). For a CSR sparse matrix `s`, the fields `s.data`, `s.indices`, and `s.indptr` contain a dense array of length `s.nnz` of  nonzero entries, a dense array of length `s.nnz` of column indices, and a list of locations (relative addresses) of the beginnings of each row in `indices` respectively. These are all normal `cupy.ndarray`s and can be passed into a kernel and then to cuSPARSE functions as normal.

Comment: Would be interested in the answer to this in a little more detail, are you able to show an example in code?